# ubuntu server cant send gmail via smtp because of the recaptcha

Tags: python, ubuntu, smtp

alright so I've been working on some program and I need to send emails from my gmail account.. so I wrote a code (irrelevent, it works)

however the mails not send until I approve the captcha..
[captcha url](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

and then this solution only work once,

What should I do to make it work as I want?
some details:
python3, smtp-module, ubuntu server built on aws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only loged into the gmail account from the server via browser and approve in the mail so that was me and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to allow less secure apps in your gmail account. [Tutorial here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/).
You might also have to disable two factor authentication.